# Laravel 5.6 Add array in multidimentional array php

Tags: php, laravel

Hi i want to merge two arrays. I have a table `positions` and `candidates`. The `candidates` table has a foreign key `pos_id`.  This is the format that i want to achieve.

```
[
  {
    "position": {
      "name": "",
      "type": "",
      "max": "",
      "candidate": [
        {
          "name": ""
        },
        {
          "name": ""
        }
      ]
   }
  },
{
```

Comment: Are you using models within your application?

Answer (score 1):

Using a `candidate` relation on the `Position` model, you will be able to achieve this by using the following:

```
Position::with('candidate')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Your relation will look like the following:

```
// Position.php

public function candidate() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Candidate', 'pos_id');
}
```